# Bootstrap full width background on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser, background-image

I'm trying to get a full width background on my bootstrap site.  I have this working for desktop browsers but the mobile devices aren't playing ball.  Here's my code (simplified);

```
html {
   background:url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #131516 !important;
}
body {
  background-color: transparent !important;  (to override bootstraps default color)
}
```

The problem I'm having is a lot of the mobile devices I'm testing on (android/iphone) don't support position fixed so the background image moves up as you scroll the page.  My site is all built in one page so moving the above code to just the body tag means the background image gets really stretched as the content (now 100% height) is long in the vertical direction.

If there's a better css way to do this that would be ideal but I can imagine jquery is what's needed.  I've tried a few of the jquery examples from [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/), none of which I could get to work properly.  Does anyone have a simple cross platform way of making this work?

Comment: bootstrap-responsive.css applies margins etc so maybe interference there. I did something similar tomrudge.com - can't remember what I did exactly without reviewing

Comment: If you don't mind loading a plugin you might want to check out backstretch: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Answer (score 0):

Make a div and use position: fixed.

```
.background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background:url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%; /* or change accordingly - not quite clear in question */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #131516 !important;
}
```

Hope this helps.